# jQuery datatable - update "Processing..." message after x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using a jQuery datatable with Bootstrap v2. When the page first loads, it displays "Processing..." which is good. It also displays this message when I change pages or sort - also good.

Most of the time the database on the backend is quick and the Processing message is only on screen for one second or less.

However in some cases, like if they are doing a search across a large number of rows, it can take several seconds for this to complete.

I want to make it so that if the Processing message is still displayed after x seconds, that I update it somehow - such as changing the style to add a background-color: yellow around it, and/or changing the mesage to "Processing longer. Please wait...".

I figured the first step was to bind to the Filter event. I was able to do that. But I wasn't able to figure out how to bind to the initial loading of the table, which does Processing... and can take a while depending on the query.

Likewise I figure this may be a fairly common thing to want to do, so I was wondering if anyone can share a snippet of code that attaches to the necessary events and will automatically find the Processing div and update it on the fly after x seconds, and then clear it so that the next time it does an Processing... message it starts back again assuming it will be quick and only changes after x seconds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can turn on a "clock" in the same event that launch the update, and then, after X seconds change the text.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the fnPreDrawCallback to start a time out, then use fnDrawCallback to clear the time out ( and reset the message state ).

I typed this on my phone, so please forgive any errors:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var extendedLoadingTimer,
        setExtendedLoadingMessage = function(){
            // Do the stuff to change the message
            // Like adding a css class and changing the text
        },
        resetLoadingMessage  = function(){
            // Do stuff to reset the message back to it's starting state
            // Like removing the css class and resetting the text
        };

    $('#your-table-id').dataTable({
        // Add your other data table options here ...
        "fnPreDrawCallback": function() { 
            // Start the timer
            extendedLoadingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                // When the timer is done ( after 400 miliseconds ) 
                // update the message
                setExtendedLoadingMessage();
            }, 400);
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            // Stop the timer from changing after its done ( although 
            // it might already be done at this point )
            clearTimeout(extendedLoadingTimer);

            // Whether the timer was done or not, always reset 
            // the message back to its original state
            resetLoadingMessage();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. And triple points for you (if only possible) for typing that into your mobile phone. I really appreciate it and this works great. If there is any way for you to contribute that code snippet or a little plugin/add-on back to the datatable community I am sure others would find this useful.

Comment: Actually I did discover a possible bug.  When the query for the Search is faster than the timeout (400ms in your sample), then timer for the setExtendedLoadingMessage() still fires.  This then leaves the status message in its "long message" state, so the next time a search is run it starts with the long message instead of with the short message and then changing to the long message 400 ms later. I checked and the value passed to clearTimeout seems to be valid. So not sure why the timer still fires? To work around this I added a call to resetLoadingMessage() at the start of fnPreDrawCallback.

Comment: Hmmm, that is unexpected. What you describe here is the reason why I clear the timeout in the drawcallback, that should stop it from executing the setExtendedLoadingMessage if it hasn't already ( by the way, the sname of the function setExtendedLoadingMessage could also have been passed as parameter to setTimeout directly ). So my guess is something else is going wrong here. Anyway, your fix is fine, and: thanks, you're welcome ( it was quite a mess typing all this out on my mobile ;-) )

Comment: Thanks. I am curious though why setExtendedLoadingMessage() still gets called even though the timer is clear. I set an alert() in that function and after the 400ms expires the function is still called, even though the clearTimeout is called first.  I added an alert() at the place where clearTimeout is called and the extendedLoadingTimer var is set and appears valid. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot it? Although it may not even be worth your trouble considering the work around seems just fine.

Comment: Well, I'm curious myself too. I simply don't have a table setup to test with. The way you're debugging seems fine, althoug I normally use console.log. The only thing I can think of is that the predrawcallback gets called more then once, meaning an old timer is overwritten with a new one and never gets cleared. A fix, if this is the case, would entail having an array of id's and clear all of them. I'll see if I can setup a table to help you along.

Comment: Yes, apparently that is exactly what is happening. I added an alert() message where the setTimeout is called. It fires once when the search is first initiated, and then a second time when the search finishes getting results from the backend, just before the results are displayed. This then caused the "long message" to get set 400ms later. So the next time a search is run, the long msg is seen first instead of the short message. Not sure its worth the trouble to fix properly tho, since the workaround is just as effective without any side effects that I can tell. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry to not have replied yet! I'm swamped, I promise to look into it in the upcoming days ;-)

Comment: Thank you Jaap. Yes I figured you have been busy with other things. Hopefully you can come up with a solution when you have the time available because I discovered a few flaws with my work-around. For example, in some cases it is possible for another search to get initiated before the work-around reset is called, and therefore the initial short message displays as the long message.  Thanks again and I look forward to the fix as time permits.